# A verb for Googling in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, derivation, technology, modern-life

In English "Google" has become a verb meaning "to search using Google".
In Finnish the name "Google" is not a valid verb, so it has been modified to "googlata" which is conjugated regularly.
How should I derive such a verb in Latin?

I want a single word, not circumlocutions like "to search using Google" or "use Google".
The core of the question is to decide the most suitable way to derive a verb from a noun.
Therefore examples of attested derivatives of similar nature and then generalization to the present situation would be the best way to answer.

My own intuition is to form the first-conjugation verb *googlare*, but I'm not sure if this is the most Latinate choice and I don't have evidence beyond my intuition.

Comment: FWIW, in Spanish it's _googlear_, -ear being the most common way (though not the only one) of regularly verbalizing a substantive. This, despite -ar being enough for a verb ending (from Latin -are)

Comment: I wonder if that mechanism has its roots in Latin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can think of many ways of going about this, but for such an unapologetically modern idea I think the best approach may be to observe how other related modern languages have solved this problem and extrapolate how a similar transformation might work.

- Spanish: *googlear*
- Portuguese: *googlar*
- Italian: *googlare*

French, though, seems to be a hold-out: I have only heard "chercher sur/avec Google."

By analogy with Italian, then, my proposal is: ***googlo, -are, -avi, -atus***.

Comment: Do Spanish, Portuguese and Italian pronounce the 'goog' bit like English?  In Welsh, the verb is "gwglo", -o/-io normal verbal ending, 'w' = [u/u:].  So would "gūglare" be better in Latin?  Wouldn't Romans read "Googlare" as "Gōglare"?

Comment: It depends on how rigorously phonetic they were with their spellings for loanwords. Most actual Romans weren't proscriptivist Latin teachers. I agree, though: _gōglō_ or _gūglō_.

Comment: "googler" is very common in French

Comment: [googlear](https://www.rae.es/observatorio-de-palabras/googlear) is non even a Spanish word, like it is not in english.

Answer (score 2):

[Mr Pck's answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4459/2733) was well considered and I agree with the approach. As Rogerides noted above, however, Latin isn't really all that happy with the *oo* bit of the name. [Per the current approach at Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google), it seems like the default would be to use **guglo** or **gugulo**, **-are**, **-avi**, **-atum** to better reflect Latin orthography.

I know OP said he wasn't interested but—just to save other people the googling—talking about this the French way would most simply produce ablative **Gugula** paired somehow with **quaero**, **-rere**, **-sivi**, **-situm**.

Comment: In French we *do* say "googler"