# Anyone know where "immorito" comes from?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, adverb, negation

Just checking since the *dictionaria [gugulabilia](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4458/a-verb-for-googling-in-latin/21060#21060)* seem to (very occasionally) include *immorito* ([glossed here as "causelessly"](https://archive.org/details/anewabridgmenta01ainsgoog/page/n49/mode/2up?view=theater); [here as "undeſervedly"](https://books.google.fr/books?id=TvJIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA870&lpg=PA870&dq=%22immorito%22)) but never whatever intermediate form produced it. It seems to most often appear in New Latin in the construction *non immorito*, "not without reason".

[Correct me if I'm wrong](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law), but this seems to be an adverbial *-o* suffix on (apparently nonexistant) *immoritus*, which in turn is a negative *im-* prefix on (apparently equally nonexistant) *moritus*. I mean, there's [*moritus* as a computer-misgenerated participle meaning "dead"](https://latinlexicon.org/paradigms.php?p1=1010171). That's off topic, right?

So is this just [*morus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morus#Etymology_2) (Gr. [*moros*, "stupid, moronic"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CF%89%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek)) with a needless *-itus* ("moronic-ish (?)") tacked on and really means "nonmoronically"? or does it come from somewhere else and something else is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mistake for *non immerito*, which indeed means "not without cause." The phrase is classical and [abundantly attested](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=non+immerito).

In your second link, it can be difficult to see, but it's actually an 'e' and not an 'o' at the end of the line there. If you look e.g. at [this transcription](https://archive.org/stream/historyofmediaev04carluoft/historyofmediaev04carluoft_djvu.txt), you get *non immerito* plenty of times and *non immorito* a couple, but if you check [in the actual text](https://archive.org/details/historyofmediaev04carluoft/page/242/mode/2up?q=immorito) where *immorito* occurs, you can see even more clearly than your examples that it's just an OCR mistake and the word is actually *immerito*.

Edit: Looked again, and even on that first link, you can see there's a difference between the second vowel and the fourth vowel. It's *immerito*, not *immorito*.

Comment: Wow. [Zoom in very closely at the end of the first paragraph on the left page that started this off](https://archive.org/details/b30538014_0001/page/134/mode/2up?view=theater) and, yup, it's a mix of printer and OCR errors there too. Thanks so much!